# Weblogic 11g: Managed Server is not starting from Weblogic console

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic12c, weblogic11g

i have some strange situation:

When i am trying to start managed server on the console i get the following error on Nodemanager:

```
PM weblogic.nodemanager.server.Handler run
WARNING: I/O error while closing socket connection
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:135)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
        at weblogic.utils.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:159)
        at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngineRunner$Context.fillBufferNetIn(JaSSLEngineRunner.java:323)
        at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngineRunner$Transition_NeedUnwrap.getNextState(JaSSLEngineRunner.java:822)
        at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngineRunner.doTransitions(JaSSLEngineRunner.java:763)
        at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngineRunner.closeInbound(JaSSLEngineRunner.java:1279)
        at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngineRunner.close(JaSSLEngineRunner.java:1365)
        at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaAbstractSSLSocket.close(JaAbstractSSLSocket.java:245)
        at weblogic.nodemanager.server.Handler.run(Handler.java:85)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

But when i am trying to start Managed Servers from command-line then it works correctly:

```
nohup ./startManagedWebLogic.sh server1 t3://xx.xx.xx.xx:7001 >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

In oracle Documentation i found that this issue can happen when in nodemanager.properties file the following line is set to false:

```
NativeVersionEnabled=false
```

After i set it to true the issue is still persists. 
The issue started after i did an Upgrade for Java from java jrockit to java JDK 1.80. I have also changed the certificates from Demo to custom.

Did someone had this issue before and knows how to fix it?

Comment: Have a look to your nodemanager.properties file. By default the node manager uses a secured connection (ssl) and you may not achieve ths configuration. You can update the nodemanager.properties file and set SecureListener=false
Then restart the node manager and test again.

Comment: Hi @Emmanuel, thanks for your comment. I have tried to run Nodemanager after changing the 'SecureListener' to false. Unfortunately the issue still persists.  The issue started after i did an Upgrade for Java from java jrockit to java JDK 1.80. I have also changed the certificates from Demo to custom.

Comment: Did you check also your machine configuration in the administration console ? In the Node Manager Tab set the Type parameter to PLAIN to force the node manager to not use SSL.

Comment: Hi @Emmanual, your solution has worked. Tnx a lot:-) Please write your solution as an answer so i can give you the status of correct solution.

Comment: Can you also explain what are the consicuances of setting the   SecureListener' to false and nodemanager to 'Plain'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the nodemanager.properties file set the SecureListener attribute to false.
In the weblogic server admin console, configure the machine to not use a secured connection with the node manager (Node Manager tab)
These 2 options configure a non secured connection between the admin server and the node manager.

Comment: Hi Emmanuel Collin, can you advise please , what i need to do in order to get a secured connection between the admin server and the node manager?