# Weblogic11g: How to restore SSL connection between Nodemanager and Managed-Server?

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic11g

I am using Weblogic 11g. Recently I have upgraded web logic ENV from  Java from Java jrockit to java JDK 1.80. I have also changed the certificates from Demo to custom. Since then I have a problem to start Managed servers from Admin console.

This is the error that I get:

```
PM weblogic.nodemanager.server.Handler run
WARNING: I/O error while closing socket connection
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:135)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
        at weblogic.utils.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:159)
        at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngineRunner$Context.fillBufferNetIn(JaSSLEngineRunner.java:323)
        at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngineRunner$Transition_NeedUnwrap.getNextState(JaSSLEngineRunner.java:822)
        at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngineRunner.doTransitions(JaSSLEngineRunner.java:763)
        at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngineRunner.closeInbound(JaSSLEngineRunner.java:1279)
        at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngineRunner.close(JaSSLEngineRunner.java:1365)
        at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaAbstractSSLSocket.close(JaAbstractSSLSocket.java:245)
        at weblogic.nodemanager.server.Handler.run(Handler.java:85)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

i got an advice from Emmanuel Collin  that suggested to change in the nodemanager.properties the line

```
SecureListener=true to SecureListener=false
```

Also he suggested to change in the Machine the secure connection from SSL to PAIN.
For more info please see: [Weblogic 11g: Managed Server is not starting from Weblogic console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44907484/weblogic-11g-managed-server-is-not-starting-from-weblogic-console/44948549#44948549).

This solution worked but now I have no SSL connection. I need to restore it. What steps should I perform to do that?

Comment: hi @halfer, tnx for your correction.

Comment: You can start with the documentation : [ssl](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/secmanage/ssl.html)

Answer (score 1):

1. Make you that you already configured the Keystore and SSL tab of your WebLogic console
2. Make sure that you have the following in your nodemanager.properties:

   SecureListener=true
   KeyStores=CustomIdentityAndCustomTrust
   CustomIdentityKeyStorePassPhrase=
   CustomIdentityKeystoreType=JKS
   CustomIdentityAlias=
   CustomIdentityPrivateKeyPassPhrase=

If you are already using SHA2 certificate, make sure that your startNodeManager.sh has something like this:

```
JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS} -Dweblogic.security.SSL.enableJSSE=true"
```